# Show message for a certain time in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, thread-sleep

I write this code for show message for certain time after changed password but It don't work :(

```
Public Sub _ChangedPassword(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    lblMsg.Text = "Passwored changed"
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000)

    FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
    Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl)

End Sub
```

Help me please

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` is done on the server, so all this code accomplishes is pausing the server thread.  You need to look into client code (e.g. javascript).

Comment: Do you want the message to show for x amount of time and then auto close itself?

Comment: @RoyvanderVelde Yes. Message show for X amount of time and then redirect to other page

Answer (score 0):

You should use a timer control instead. In case you are not using multi-threading you should never use `Thread.sleep()` as it will hang your program for 20 seconds.

However, if you *really* want this method than you have the wrong order of the following two lines (as it first sets the text and then sleeps):

```
lblMsg.Text = "Password changed"
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000)
```

As they should be:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000)
lblMsg.Text = "Password changed"

'Do the rest
FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl)
```

Comment: Did not see the asp.net tag but maybe this can help either way.